# Error installing mongodb on armv71 ubuntu board

Tags: linux, mongodb

I try installing mongodb with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install mongodb
```

However I get the following error:

```
Package mongodb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate
```

I want to install this on a Linux dev board which has an armv71 cpu, how would I fix it.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ ll help you

Comment: That doesn't work since I'm trying to install on an armv7 board and not an x86 64 bit

Comment: I'm fine with using an older version of mongodb as well, but I need it to run on my armv71 board.